# Converting polygon to raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, buffer

I'm just learning the basics of Arcmap and I'm currently stuck on doing this.

Ive got a road with a 500m buffer (polygon) and I'm attempting to convert it into a raster so I can reclassify it into (1(suitable) and 0(unsuitable) in order to use the data for the boolean tool so I can have 2 factors merge into 1 area.

However I'm currently stuck on converting the polygon into actual data that I can reclassify because currently I'm just getting an errors, or no data.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you have tried and the errors you have received.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'polygon to raster' tool (toolboxes\system toolboxes\conversion tools.tbx\to raster\polygon to raster).

For the 'value field' you would have to create a dummy variable in your buffer layer, so that the resulting raster has a '1' for cells with the buffer, and '0'/'nodata' for the rest of the cells. So each polygon feature should have an attribute with a value '1'. You can do this by adding a field in the attribute table and executing the 'field calculator' on this field (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm).

After that you would have to fill the rasters 'nodata' cells with '0', you dan do this via the raster calculator(see http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010059).